# Using CTEs in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a plpgsql function in Postgres 8.4 that uses a CTE inside but it's giving me a syntax error. Are they not allowed?

(Something like this, bear in mind I'm writing this without my code.)

```
With foo as (SELECT id,a as alias FROM foo);
UPDATE zoo SET b = alias FROM foo WHERE id = foo.id;
^Error here
```

Comment: remove the semicolon after foo)

Comment: That's not the problem, I already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH foo as (
    SELECT id
       , a AS zalias
    FROM footable
    )
UPDATE zoo z
SET b = f.zalias
FROM foo f
WHERE z.id = f.id
   ;
```

NOTE: "alias" is a reserved word.

UPDATE as of per comment by Erwin Brandstetter: the CTE is not valid in a UPDATE statement in 8.4. You'll need 9.1 or higher.
Since a CTE is actually a kind of instant view, you could put the CTE body inside a view, and refer to that.

```
CREATE VIEW foo as (
    SELECT id
       , a AS zalias
    FROM footable
    );
UPDATE zoo z
SET b = f.zalias
FROM foo f
WHERE z.id = f.id
   ;
DROP VIEW foo;
```

Comment: `alias` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL:1999 only, but not in later versions of the standard, and not in PostgreSQL. So it should be safe to use freely.

Comment: I stand corrected. I seem to remember that when functions had no named parameters (pg 8.3 ?) alias was a keyword. I still prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the temp view approach.

Answer (score 2):

A [data modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (that's what it is) is **not available in PostgreSQL 8.4**.

Your statement would work with minor patches as @wildplasser demonstrates in PostgreSQL **9.1** or later, where data modifying CTE were introduced.

A very simple replacement for 8.4 would be a **subquery**:

```
UPDATE zoo z
SET    b = f.alias
FROM  (SELECT id, a as alias FROM foo) f
WHERE  z.id = f.id;
```

The example can be further simplified (but maybe the real world case is more complex):

```
UPDATE zoo z
SET    b = f.a
FROM   foo f
WHERE  z.id = f.id;
```

Remember to table-qualify the otherwise ambiguous column name `id` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Is it really a data modifying CTE? Looks like a common one, as it is not a DDL statement inside the CTE.

Comment: @vyegorov: I was not sure myself at first. But I studied the manual and tried the test case on an 8.4 cluster: no joy.

Comment: I hesitated to also add that final reduction to `update ... FROM ...`

Comment: @wildplasser: I only added it after I had seen that you didn't ... :)

Comment: LOL. In most cases, the CTE will be used to wrap more complex queries. Including nested CTE's. Maybe I should add a recursive version, too? ;-) BTW:my habit of adding 'z' to suspect keywords should be pronounced just like the Germans pronounce 'the' ;-) ALSO: No SQL keyword starts with 'z'.